# Yii Active Record search not working with default attributes values

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, yii

I have a `tax` table with following fields:

```
tax_id            (tinyint)
tax_chat_type_id  (enum)     default  '0'
tax_min_value     (decimal)  default  0.10
tax_max_value     (decimal)  default  2.00
tax_obs           (varchar)
```

When a search is performed the method `search()` on `Tax` model is called by `$model->search()` on `CGridView` on view to populate a table/grid:

```
public function search()
{
    $sort = new CSort();
    $sort->defaultOrder = 'tax_id DESC';

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->compare('tax_id', $this->tax_id, false, 'OR');
    $criteria->compare('tax_chat_type_id', $this->tax_chat_type_id, true, 'OR');
    $criteria->compare('tax_min_value', $this->tax_min_value, true, 'OR');
    $criteria->compare('tax_max_value', $this->tax_max_value, true, 'OR');
    $criteria->compare('tax_obs', $this->tax_obs, true, 'OR');

    return new CActiveDataProvider(
        $this,  Array('criteria' => $criteria, 'sort' => $sort)
    );
}
```

But when I modify the value of any field that have a default value, the register of this value not is disappears from table/grid. If I return value to default value, the register come back to table/grid.

What is happening? Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

A `var_dump($criteria);` returns:

```
object(CDbCriteria)[89]
     public 'select' => string '*' (length=1)
     public 'distinct' => boolean false
     public 'condition' => string '((tax_chat_type_id LIKE :ycp0) OR (tax_min_value LIKE :ycp1)) OR (tax_max_value LIKE :ycp2)' (length=91)
     public 'params' => 
         array (size=3)
             ':ycp0' => string '%0%' (length=3)
             ':ycp1' => string '%0.10%' (length=6)
             ':ycp2' => string '%2.00%' (length=6)
     public 'limit' => int -1
     public 'offset' => int -1
     public 'order' => string '' (length=0)
     public 'group' => string '' (length=0)
     public 'join' => string '' (length=0)
     public 'having' => string '' (length=0)
     public 'with' => null
     public 'alias' => null
     public 'together' => null
     public 'index' => null
     public 'scopes' => null
     private '_e' (CComponent) => null
     private '_m' (CComponent) => null
```

Comment: Remove 'OR' parameter from $criteria->compare()

Comment: Not working, and I need the query with OR's not AND's by default.